# SQL querying across tables to identify an aggregate value for a particular attribute

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to query available seating on airplanes that fly along routes that stop, unload, and load on more people.

I've been trying to query across the tables but I am running into problems with accessing other queried tables' attributes within separate subqueries that are out of scope for the others. Would this be possible to do with a WITH ___ AS query?

The first two tables here are examples of data that I am working with to hopefully produce the desired result.
The first table just below is a series of connections for passengers who get on the plane, 329, at start_airport and get off at end_airport

```
 start_airport | end_airport
---------------+------------
            78 |          76
            78 |          76
            78 |          74
            77 |          76
            77 |          76
            77 |          75
            77 |          75
            77 |          75
            77 |          74
            77 |          74
            76 |          75
            76 |          75
            76 |          75
            76 |          75
            76 |          75
            76 |          74
            75 |          74
            75 |          74
            75 |          74
            75 |          74
            75 |          74

 airplane | airport_id | airplane_size
----------+------------+-------------
      329 |         78 |           67
      329 |         77 |           67
      329 |         76 |           67
      329 |         75 |           67
      329 |         74 |           67
```

The table I would like to result for this particular set of data, where available seating is updated for each stop along the route:

```
 airplane | airport_id | available_seating
----------+------------+------------------
      329 |         78 |               64
      329 |         77 |               57
      329 |         76 |               55
      329 |         75 |               59
```

Comment: How do you determine which airport should be counted first? Is there any other column that determines order of airport to consider, for eg to say 77 comes after 78?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be resolved by left joining the sets of sum of start and end airports from `connections`. `SUM` analytic functions can produce cumulative result for a given expression.

The only thing you would require, which you have not yet shown is an id column which indicates the sequence of the order of stoppages. I have just used `ID` as an integer sequence, it may be a date column as well if you have one.Without any such column, it isn't possible to determine the direction of a running SUM.

```
WITH st AS (
     SELECT start_airport,
            COUNT(*) AS cnt
     FROM connections
     GROUP BY start_airport
),en AS (
     SELECT end_airport,
            COUNT(*) AS cnt
     FROM connections
     GROUP BY end_airport
) SELECT airplane,
         airport_id,
         airplane_size - SUM( coalesce( st.cnt ,0) - coalesce(en.cnt,0) ) 
 OVER( ORDER BY id --You should use the appropriate id column that determines order.
                   ) as available_seating
  FROM stops t2 left
      JOIN st ON t2.airport_id = st.start_airport
  LEFT JOIN en ON t2.airport_id = en.end_airport
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5793b3f2cd935a6ece2451152120ad5a)